# The Flow of Dispatch Event in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dispatcher

I'm studying Symfony and I'm trying with Dispatch Event Component.

I Understand that there are

- Dispatcher (component)
- Event ( that pass information to Listener )
- Listener ( the logic )

I created a simple example in my route

```
 /**
 * @Route("/evento", name="evento")
 */
public function eventoAction()
{
    $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    $listener = new StoreListener($this->get('mailer'));
    $dispatcher->addListener(StoreEvents::STORE_ORDER,array($listener,'onFooAction'),25);
    $order = new Ordini();
    $order->setName('ordine nuovo -'.rand(0,100));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($order);
    $em->flush();
    $event = new FilterOrderEvent($order);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(StoreEvents::STORE_ORDER,$event);
    return $this->render('::event.html.twig');
}
```

StoreEvent with Contain the Const String

```
namespace AppBundle\Events;


final class StoreEvents
{
    /**
     * The store.order event is thrown each time an order is created
     * in the system.
     *
     * The event listener receives an
     * Acme\StoreBundle\Event\FilterOrderEvent instance.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const STORE_ORDER = 'store.order';

}
```

The Event that I pass to Listener

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Events;

use AppBundle\Entity\Ordini;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class FilterOrderEvent extends Event
{
    protected $order;
    public function __construct(Ordini $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * @return Ordini
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

}
```

And The Listener

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Events;


use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
class StoreListener
{
    protected $mail;

    /**
     * StoreListener constructor.
     * @param $mail
     */
    public function __construct($mail)
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }


    public function onFooAction(Event $event)
    {
        var_dump($event);
        var_dump($event->getOrder());
        echo "fooAction";

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject($event->getOrder()->getName())
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('send@example2.com)
            ->setBody('Test')
        ;
        $this->mail->send($message);

    }

}
```

all these stuff Work but I want to Understand where I have to declare the dispatcher.
I have to declare for each controller ?

```
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
```

even the add listener ( or addSubscriber)

```
$dispatcher->addListener(StoreEvents::STORE_ORDER,array($listener,'onFooAction'),25);
```

I don't think this is the best practice to Declare every Time the new Dispatcher
or new addListener

**UPDATE**

I created another Action

```
    /**
     * @Route("/evento2", name="evento2")
     */
    public function evento2Action()
    {
        $order = new Ordini();
        $order->setName('ordine nuovo -'.rand(0,100));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();

        $event = new FilterOrderEvent($order);
        $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(StoreEvents::STORE_ORDER,$event);
        return $this->render('::event.html.twig');
    }
```

And create my service:

services:

```
create_order_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Events\StoreListener
    arguments: ["@swiftmailer.mailer"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: store.order, method: onFooAction
```

all work. But now I'd like to know the best practice or when Create listener by service and when I have to use `addListener` or `addSubscriber`

Comment: There is one global dispatcher accessible via the container. $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');  Read more here especially about how to attach your own listeners. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/index.html

Comment: thanks @Cerad, I use ` $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');` instead of `$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();`.
But I don't Understand Where I can add the listener. In this example http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/event_dispatcher.html The author add the listener in frontController.

Comment: Are you creating your own framework or using the Symfony 2 framework?  The link I gave you is for the Symfony 2 framework.

Comment: @Cerad No, I'm using symfony, but I see that part to understand where addListener is place.

Comment: @monkeyUser You don't need to call `addListener` manually. You've defined your listener service and tagged it as an event listener -- tagging as such will register it with the event dispatcher.

Comment: @solocommand exactly, this is what I looking for. Because I'm studying even component book, I mistake with symfony environment and component  stand alone. thanks